# How to remove a set number of characters counting from the end of a string?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32, irvine32

I have to remove a certain number of characters(let's say 3) from the end of a string. For this particular string it works when I find 'Z', and then make it point to W by sub edi, 3, and then storing the rest of the string with 0's.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
source BYTE "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 0

.code
main PROC

mov edi, OFFSET source
mov al, 'Z'                  ; search for Z
mov ecx, LENGTHOF source
cld
repne scasb       ; repeat while not equal
sub edi, 3         ; now points to W

mov al, 0         
rep stosb        ; stores all characters after W with 0.

mov edx, OFFSET source
call WriteString
call CrlF

exit
main ENDP
end main
```

However, I want to make this code work with different strings i.e. if the source is changed by the user to say some thing different(E.g.source byte  "This is a string", 0).  For that purpose I tried finding 0(the end of the string), as my code shows below. But it doesn't work, It just outputs the whole string.

What should I do to ensure that the code still works even if the string is changed without having to change the search for the end of the string every time?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
source BYTE "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 0

.code
main PROC

mov edi, OFFSET source
mov al, '0'                  ; search for end of string
mov ecx, LENGTHOF source
cld
repne scasb       ; repeat while not equal
sub edi, 3         ; now points to W ??

mov al, 0         
rep stosb        ; stores all characters after W with 0.

mov edx, OFFSET source
call WriteString
call CrlF

exit
main ENDP
end main
```

Comment: Try using the answer to your previous question. If you have any problem, post your code to see what the problem might be (come on, you can do it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove everything after a certain character in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37036950/how-do-i-remove-everything-after-a-certain-character-in-a-string)

Comment: Asking the same question twice isn't going to get you a different answer.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez  I have added the code with more information.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer It's not the same question. I am asking something different although it is similar. I have edited the question now.

Comment: store a terminating 0 two chars before the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use repeat move string byte. I got this from another website. In your case you would move the length of your string - 10 into cx.

```
mov     ax,@data 
mov     ds,ax     ;initialize ds 
mov     es,ax     ;and es 
lea     si,[str1] ;si points to source string 
lea     di,[str2] ;di points to dest string 
cld               ;set df=0 (increasing) 
mov     cx,5      ;# of chars in string1 
rep movsb         ;copy the string
```

Comment: I want to delete the characters from a string without copying it to another. Thanks for your answer though. Appreciate your effort. :)